# Подградье подгражане

Tags: этимология

Существуют ли в русском языке слова подгородье/подградье и подгражане наряду с топонимом Подмосковье?

Добавлено:

Острожская библия 1Пар.6:40
"И даша имъ гевронъ въ земли иудине и подъградиа ихъ по окрестъ"

Подградие - дореволюционная норма написания, в словарях присутствует.

Comment: Подмосковье – не термин. Гляньте в словарь, посмотрите, что такое термин. Заодно и подградье поищите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слов "подгородье"/"подградье" и "подгражане" я ни разу за свою жизнь не встречал.

В то время как слово "подгражане" звучит для русского уха непонятно, смысл слов "подгородье" и "подградье" самоочевиден, и эти слова обладают определённым изяществом. С моей точки зрения, их можно ввести в употребление.

Можно также сказать "предградье". (Википедия утверждает, что такое слово существует.)  Привычнее, однако, будут "посад" и "подол". А надёжней всего будет сказать "предместье".

Answer (score 2):

Яндекс – переводчик подсказывает, что у части славянских языков «пригород» называется словом «предместье", но вот у хорватов это уже «u predgrađu», у сербов – «предграђе», у боснийцев «predgrađe», у болгар «предградие», у белорусов «прыгарад».

Вполне возможно, что и в каких то диалектах русского найдутся словоформы, близкие к вышеупомянутым.